# Prevent form submission based on the response received from ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, form-submit

I have a form which gets submitted once the `input` of type `submit` button is clicked. Now i want add a validation such that if an unique ID is already exists in the database then the a alert message should display and form should not be submitted. For this I am using Ajax to check the existence of Unique ID, here is my ajax Code: 
 
`function validate(){
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Controller/Method",
            data: '{barcode:"' + barcode + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json,charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (response) {
              //here i want to display the alert message
              // and some code to stop the form submission.
            }
        });
}`

Here's my input button code: 
`<input type="submit" value="Go" onclick="return validate()" />`

I have tried `return false` but it is not working.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll surely add this in the project. However the question remains same that is how am I going to stop the form submission once found that `ID` is failed to insert due to duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Double negate the logic to arrive at a solution using asynchronous code. *Instead of stopping form submission if the id exists already, only submit the form if it doesn't.*

As pointed out in comment you would still need  logic on the server to generate an error for form submission if the id was created in the time between first checking it existed and attempting to process form data based on the assumption it still doesn't exist.

It may be better to submit form data and the id in a single server request.