# form is submitted even if validation failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to check if an email exists before allowing to submit the form.

if the email exists, I get the alert which I added to test the form, but it still submits the form and moves to "login.asp". 
I also added "event.preventDefault();" to try and stop it, but still it happens
Here is my code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() { //newly added 
            $('#Submit').click(function() {
                alert('in');
                var emailVal = $('#email').val(); // assuming this is a input text field
                $.post('User_RegisterCheck.asp', {
                    'email': emailVal
                }, function(data) {
                    if (data == 'exist') {
                        alert('exits');
                        return false;
                        event.preventDefault();
                    } else $('#FormRegID').submit();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" id="FormRegID" name="FormRegID" action="login.asp">

        <div class="form-group ">
            <label for="email" class="control-label">email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control w-75" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email" required>

        </div>
        <input type="image" name="Submit" src="/images/button_login-register.png" border="0" alt="Submit" id="Submit" style="width: 209px;" />
        </div>

    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I validate the email?

Comment: Part of the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8664680/5267751 (use onsubmit instead of click)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent form submission based on the response received from ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907567/prevent-form-submission-based-on-the-response-received-from-ajax-call)

Comment: @user202729 the title is certainly a dupe, but it provides no workable answer and isn't a useful solution.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The answer works (it contains the same content as your answer), just not a copy-pastable code. The asker would need to understand the content and do some (more) research to write the code...

Comment: Exactly my point :) Also note that the approach in the first dupe wouldn't work because the call here is async.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you stop the submission too late; you're doing it in the AJAX request which is asynchronous. The form has already been sent by the time that occurs.

To fix this call `preventDefault()` on the event, regardless of the state of the AJAX request. Then you can make the request and if the validation passes you can submit the `form` element (note: **not** the jQuery object containing the form) and allow the data to be sent to the server. Try this:

```html
<form method="post" id="FormRegID" name="FormRegID" action="login.asp">
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label for="email" class="control-label">email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control w-75" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email" required>
  </div>
  <input type="image" name="Submit" src="/images/button_login-register.png" border="0" alt="Submit" id="Submit" style="width: 209px;" />
  </div>
</form>
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#FormRegID').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var emailVal = $('#email').val();

    $.post('User_RegisterCheck.asp', {
      'email': emailVal
    }, function(data) {
      if (data.trim() !== 'exist') 
        this.submit();
    });
  });
});
```

Note that this hooks to the `submit` event of the `form`, not the `click` of the `button`.

I would also suggest you return a boolean value in a formal data structure from your AJAX call, such as JSON, instead of plaintext. This is because whitespace can cause problems with the latter being interpreted correctly.

Comment: Now it's submitting the form regardless of the validation. I tried to debug it, and it's not even committing the AJAX call, but immediately sent the form

Comment: Check the console for errors in the AJAX request. Also check the exact response of the request - it's possible the plain text response is causing issues.

Comment: The ajax worked before, and I don't get any error on the console https://www.yomyom.net/test.asp

Comment: Which browser are you testing with? Your link works fine for me in Chrome 78 on Windows - ie. I see validation errors when submitting an empty field, and when submitting an invalid email address, and the form submits correctly when a valid email is entered.

Comment: Well that's down to your AJAX method. Check the response that's coming back is `exist`.

Comment: you need to try to select an email that already exits - test@test.com.
as you can see, the ajax return exits:
https://www.yomyom.net/User_RegisterCheck.asp?email=test@test.com

I also added alerts whether it exists or not (I was unable to add the code in this comment but you can see the source page) - but as I said, it seems the page doesn't even commit this condition

Comment: That's because you've hooked to the `Submit` event, not `submit`. Remember that JS is case-sentitive.